# If an event $\{X_n = 1\}$ happens infinitely often with probability 1, why can't $X_n \overset{a.s.}\to 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I saw an example in a book where $X_n \sim^{iid} Bern(\frac{1}{n})$. The book claims that since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\{X_n = 1\}) = \infty$, the event $\{X_n = 1\}$ happens infinitely often with probability 1 (by Borel-Cantelli). Why can't $X_n \overset{a.s.}\to 1$? It seems very obvious to me but I cannot get it to work by the book's definition of almost sure convergence, that $X_n \overset{a.s.}\to X$ means:

$$
P(\{\omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty}X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)\})=1.
$$

Is there a way to show this using this very definition of almost sure convergence? Thanks!

Comment: Are we assuming the $X_n$ are independent?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, sorry to not have mentioned that!

Comment: Perhaps the simplest approach: the series $\sum P(X_n=0)$ and $\sum P(X_n=1)$ both diverges and $(X_n)$ is independent hence $\limsup\{X_n=0\}$ and $\limsup\{X_n=1\}$ are both almost sure, that is, almost surely $X_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$ and $X_n=1$ for infinitely many $n$. Thus $(X_n)$ diverges almost surely.

Comment: Or you could notice that $X_n\overset{p}\to 0$ and hence $X_n$ can't converge a.s. to anything other than $0$ - which it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the $X_n$ are independent, then it follows from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma that
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_n=1\}\right)=1. $$
(See for example [here](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-BC.pdf) for a proof of the Borel-Canelli lemmas.) However,
$$\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=1\} \right) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k=1\}\right)=0, $$
since for any $n$,
$$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k=1\} \right)=\prod_{k=n}^\infty\mathbb P(X_k=1)=\prod_{k=n}^\infty\frac1k=0 $$
and hence
$$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k=1\}\right)\leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty \{X_k=1\}\right)=0. $$
Since $$\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} \{X_n=1\}\right) \ne \mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=1\}\right), $$
it is clear that
$$\mathbb P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=1\}\right) $$
does not exist, and so $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $1$.

By similar computations we find that
$$\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=0\}\right)=0<1=P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=0\}\right), $$

so $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $0$.

Footnote: Recall that

> $$X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}\longrightarrow X\iff \mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} \{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}\right)=1$$
>
> for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Since in this case $\mathbb P(X_n\in\{0,1\})=1$ for all $n$, taking $\varepsilon<\frac12$ justifies the use of e.g. $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X_n=1\}$ as opposed to $\{\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_n\}=1$.

Comment: What does $\lim\{X_n=1\}$ have to do w/ $[\lim X_n]=1$?

Comment: @BCLC What exactly do you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n$?

Comment: Math1000, $\lim X_n = \limsup X_n = \liminf X_n$...we had this argument w/ Did remember?

Comment: $$X_n\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}\longrightarrow X\iff \mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} \{|X_n-X|<\varepsilon\}\right)=1 $$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Since in this case $\mathbb P(X_n\in\{0,1\})=1$ there is no distinction to be made; take e.g. $\varepsilon<\frac12$.

Comment: Math1000, uggghhhh so what's wrong w/ my argument? That seems to be consistent contrapositive of #4 there, w/c says merely $\ge$...

Comment: Btw if that's the case, why don't you put in your answer?

Comment: Didn't notice the edit til just now. +1

Comment: Btw, am I correct in saying that you used only one of the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas and only once unlike Did and Milind? :O

Comment: @Did's argument is a refinement of mine.

Answer (score 1):

By the second Borel-Cantelli lemma we have that $X_n=1$ infinitely often with probability 1, as the book states.

The definition given says that convergence occurs a.s. if the probability that the limit equals $0$ is $1$. This means that the for every $\epsilon$, there exists an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|X_n(\omega)|<\epsilon$ for a.e. $\omega$.

But we know that $X_n(\omega)=1$ infinitely often for a.e. $\omega$, and hence you cannot find any such $N$. So in fact the relevant probability is $0$ and not $1$, and so the a.s. convergence to $0$ does not occur.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-\frac1n) = \infty$ also, this means that $X_n=0$ infinitely often as well. Then you can repeat the above argument to conclude that $X_n$ does not converge a.s. to $1$.

Comment: This is similar to the argument of Math1000. What is the relationship b/w $\lim [X_n = 1]$ and $[\lim X_n] = 1$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\lim [X_n=1]$? Is it the limit of $\mathrm{Pr}(X_n=1)$?

Comment: Milind, $\lim[X_n = 1] = \liminf[X_n = 1] = \limsup[X_n = 1]$. However, $\lim X_n = \liminf X_n = \limsup X_n$

Comment: But could you explain the notation $\lim [X_n=1]$ (or $\liminf, \limsup$ of the same)? I have not seen it before.

Comment: Milind, see my answer. Essentially, you and Math1000 seem to be arguing that $\omega \in \lim[X_n = 1] \to \lim X_n(\omega) = 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\liminf X_n$$

$$ = \sup [\inf_{n \ge 1} X_n, \inf_{n \ge 2} X_n, ... ]$$

$$ = \sup [0, 0, ... ] = 0$$

$$\limsup X_n$$

$$ = \inf [\sup_{n \ge 1} X_n, \sup_{n \ge 2} X_n, ... ]$$

$$ = \inf [1, 1, ... ] = 1$$

Since

$$\limsup X_n \ne \liminf X_n,$$

$\lim X_n$ does not exist.

---

Note that the reason we say that $\inf_{n \ge m} X_n = 0 \ \forall m \ge 1$ is $X_n = 0 \ \text{i.o.}$ because $X_n = 0 \ \text{i.o.}$ means that $\forall m \ge 1, \exists n \ge m$ s.t. $X_n = 0$.

///ly, the reason we say that $\sup_{n \ge m} X_n = 1 \ \forall m \ge 1$ is $X_n = 1 \ \text{i.o.}$ because $X_n = 1 \ \text{i.o.}$ means that $\forall m \ge 1, \exists n \ge m$ s.t. $X_n = 1$.

Comment: Not an answer. This takes for granted that $X_n=0$ infinitely often, the fact the OP is confused with.

Comment: @Did What do you mean by 'takes for granted'? user136503 is asking why it is not the case that almost surely $X_n \to 1$. My answer is that $\lim X_n$ does not exist based on facts 1. $X_n = 0$ i.o. 2. $X_n = 1$ i.o. How is this not an answer?